# How should I manage dates that take a weird format when I use read_excel in R?

Tags: r, date, format

I am a beginner in R, and I encountered the following problem

Some dates, all coming from the same file appear in a weird format. Here is an example :

[Examples of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCATm.png)

As shown in the above picture, I have in the original file some proper dates with dd/mm/yyyy format.

After using read_excel to import the file in R, I noticed that some of these dates now appear as the number of day since 1899-12-30, that I changed with the following line of code :

```
as.Date(as.integer(file_name$`column_name`),origin="1899-12-30")
```

But I didn't immediately notice that other dates were not handled properly by R, and I have no idea what these numbers mean, since it is not the number of seconds since 1899-12-30.

I am currently using the following packages :

- tidyverse
- readxl
- dplyr
- lubridate

Does anyone have any idea where the problem comes from ?
I have to use the date format since I will have to do calculations with it, so how can I handle this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(1660780800, origin = '1970-01-01')`.  1660780800 is the number of seconds from the start of the POSIX epoch (1st January 1970) to the date in question.

Comment: The larger number looks like a date/time value rather than just a date. Try `as.POSIXct(1660780800, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")`